# TinyMCE how add input field in dialog hyperlink plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Looking at the documentation, tinymce allows you to add a selectable list with the property `link_list`, but I need to add input fields instead of a list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        link_list: [
            {title: 'Home', value: '/'},
            {title: 'Category Level 1', menu: [
                {title: 'C1 Page 1', value: '/c1/foo'},
                {title: 'C1 Page 2', value: '/c1/bar'},
                {title: 'Category Level 2', menu: [
                  {title: 'C2 Page 1', value: '/c1/c2/foo'},
                  {title: 'C2 Page 2', value: '/c1/c2/bar'}
               ]}
            ]}
        ]
    });
    </script>
    
    <form method="post" action="dump.php">
        <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    </form>
```